# How can I save to my web config without losing my session?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I thought about saving all sessions variables to hiddens and then resaving those values back into session after I changed the web config..but there has GOT to be another way.

Any help?

Comment: when you change web.config, the AppDomain is reloaded,probably that is why you losing your info ,i think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change the web.config the app restarts and thus the session is lost (for inProc session). I remember changing the session provider to store session data in files to get over the session getting lost.

Or maybe you can use the Sql Server to store the session (sessionState mode="SQLServer") in web.config) but I don't know if this keeps your session state when modifying the web.config file (though it should).

Hope you find it helpful.

Comment: SQL Server is the non-volatile solution to storing session data out-of-process. The other out-of-process solution is the ASP.NET session state server; it's subject to loss on system restarts, but performs better than SQL Server.